# PowerShell 5.1 Why is my $sqlResult acting like a global variable

Tags: powershell

Why is my $sqlResult variable acting like a global variable. I didn't expect that.

```
function Main
{
param([string] $arg1)
    DoWork1 -arg1 $arg1
    DoWork2
}

function DoWork1
{
param([string] $arg1)

    $sqlResult = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query 'select * from customer' -ServerInstance '(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB' -Database 'Database1' -OutputAs DataTables
    $sqlResult | Out-Host      
}

function DoWork2
{
    $sqlResult | Out-Host
}

Main -arg1 "Hello World"
```

[image]

Comment: I believe you have defined `$sqlResult` some time along your testing in the script scope hence why now it's outputting unexpected results. Try restarting your powershell session.

Comment: if you add it as answer, i'll give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible explanation for what you were experiencing was that `$sqlResult` would be previously defined in the **Parent Scope** of your functions  ([`$script:` scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.2#parent-and-child-scopes)), and `DoWork2` was outputting said variable. In this case would be pretty confusing to see where the issue was because both `$sqlResult` variables, *the one in the script scope and the one receiving the output from your SQL query in `DoWork1` function*, happen to be objects with same properties and values.

In this example we can see the issue better:

```
function Main {
    param([string] $arg1)

    DoWork1 -arg1 $arg1; DoWork2
}

function DoWork1 {
    param([string] $arg1)

    $sqlResult = $arg1
    $sqlResult
}

function DoWork2 { $sqlResult }

$sqlResult = 'something else'
Main -arg1 "Hello World"
```